# NSURLSession Crash swift iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, crash, nsurl, nsurlsession

I have a function to retrieve data from an API using an URL link.

Everything works on iOS 8 but when I run it on a device with iOS 7, the following bit of swift code fails and the app crashes -  the last line (when setting the session configuration) is the one that makes it crash.

I don't understand why, is it some feature not available in iOS 7 and how can I fix it?

```
var defaultConfigObject = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
defaultConfigObject.allowsCellularAccess = true

var session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession()
session = NSURLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject)
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Why are you doing this declaration and definition in two lines `var session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession()
session = NSURLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject)`.
Try doing this whole thing like this `var session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject)`